# Excel VBA: Sorting a range using a permutation array as the key

Tags: sorting, excel, vba

I'd like to sort a range using a permutation stored in an array. I tried something like this:

```
Sub PermSort()
  Dim Perm() As Variant
  Perm = Array(1, 6, 7, 8, 5, 2, 4, 3)
  Range("A1:A8").Sort Key1:=Perm, order1:=xlAscending
End Sub
```

but it doesn't work, since Key1 is expected to be a Range.
Is it possible to somehow use the build in `.Sort` method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[From here:](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/SortingArrays.aspx)

*The VBA language has no support for sorting the values stored in an array. One method that can be used to sort arrays is to put the data on to a worksheet, sort the data on the worksheet, and then read back the values from the worksheet into the array. The other method for sorting arrays is to use the QSort algorithm to sort the array in place. This page describes both methods, with variations on the QSort method.*

HTH!

PS:

The code for the first method is:

```
Sub SortViaWorksheet()
    Dim Arr(1 To 5) As String ' this is the array to be sorted
    Dim WS As Worksheet ' temporary worksheet
    Dim R As Range
    Dim N As Long

    ' fill up the array with some
    ' aribtrary values.
    Arr(1) = "aaa"
    Arr(2) = "zzz"
    Arr(3) = "mmm"
    Arr(4) = "ttt"
    Arr(5) = "bbb"

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    ' create a new sheet
    Set WS = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add

    ' put the array values on the worksheet
    Set R = WS.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(Arr) - LBound(Arr) + 1, 1)
    R = Application.Transpose(Arr)

    ' sort the range
    R.Sort key1:=R, order1:=xlAscending, MatchCase:=False

    ' load the worksheet values back into the array
    For N = 1 To R.Rows.Count
        Arr(N) = R(N, 1)
    Next N

    ' delete the temporary sheet
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    WS.Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    ' test/debug/confirmation
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        Debug.Print Arr(N)
    Next N   
End Sub
```

For the second one there is a Qsort standard routine. You may download it from the original site.